# How to check all child when parent is checked in winform C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Hi all I am creating a tree-view dynamically at run-time. My Tree view is below. When I check the Master(Parent) The Child Register Masters and Class Masters want to Checked Automatically.

But I can't code Node4.checked = true like this. Because I have created this treeview in runtime.

Please give any valuable suggestion.

[image]

**UpDated Question -**

```
private void MenuRights_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("data");
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));           
            dt.Columns.Add("menu_name");
            dt.Columns.Add("parentid", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("menu_key");           

            hp.getConnStr();
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(hp.myConnStr);
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select * from mcs_menu_details", connection);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                //dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { Reader[0].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString(), Reader[2].ToString(), Reader[3].ToString() });
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["id"] = Convert.ToInt32(Reader[0].ToString());
                row["menu_name"] = Reader[1].ToString();
                if (Reader[2].ToString() != Convert.ToString(0))
                {
                    row["parentid"] = Convert.ToInt32(Reader[2].ToString());
                }
                else { row["parentid"] = DBNull.Value; }
                row["menu_key"] = Reader[3].ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(row);             
            }
            connection.Close();

            //Use a DataSet to manage the data
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            //add a relationship
            ds.Relations.Add("rsParentChild", ds.Tables["data"].Columns["id"],ds.Tables["data"].Columns["parentid"]);

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["data"].Rows)
            {
                if (dr["parentid"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(dr["menu_name"].ToString());
                    root.Tag = dr["menu_key"].ToString();
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
                    PopulateTree(dr, root);
                }
            }
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }

        public void PopulateTree(DataRow dr, TreeNode pNode)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dr.GetChildRows("rsParentChild"))
            {
                TreeNode cChild = new TreeNode(row["menu_name"].ToString());
                cChild.Tag = row["menu_key"].ToString();
                pNode.Nodes.Add(cChild);
                //Recursively build the tree
                PopulateTree(row, cChild);
            }
        }
```

The Above Code is help me to create the treeview. This may given you a clear view of my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to re-think this UI.  What could checking "System" possibly do?  The friction is most evident in "Help".

Answer (score 2):

You can simply iterate through the tree to check each node

Let's suppose node is the `TreeNode` in tree which is checked and you want to check all the children of this `TreeNode`

```
CheckAllChildren(TreeNode node)
{
    foreach(TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
    {
       child.Checked = true;
       CheckAllChildren(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: This method will call itself.Is it fine?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine as long as method calls itself finite times

Comment: @HarisHasan I was tried this, but Method must have a return type error occur. Can I add Private void in this?.

Comment: Oh its works but I want to call this CheckAllChildren function in button click event. How I Make when treeview parent click itself. Any idea.

Answer (score 2):

Note sure to fully understand what you're asking here....

If you're creating your treeview dynamically, I assume you're adding nodes using `Nodes.Add(...)`. Just specifies `Checked` as `true` to check your inserted node.

```
private void MainForm2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode
    {
        Text = "Mytext",
        Checked = true
    };

    this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
}
```

---

If you want to check your child nodes at runtime, just do some recursion like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
    {
        this.CheckChildrens(this.treeView1.SelectedNode);
    }
}

private void CheckChildrens(TreeNode node)
{
    node.Checked = true;

    foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
    {
        this.CheckChildrens(child);
    }
}
```

But don't call directly `CheckChildrens(...)` without caution from `AfterCheck` event handler (if you want to take the new checked node into account) or you'll have a nice `StackOverflow` exception.

Comment: Thanks ken2k, please see my updated question. it may be give you a clear way.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this method without recursion, put this code in `AfterCheck` event.

```
        if (e.Node.FirstNode != null)
        {
            TreeNode tn = e.Node.FirstNode;
            while (tn != null) // check all childrens.
            {
                tn.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
                tn = tn.NextNode;
            }
        }
```